# Xcode appears to be installed but xcodebuild is unusable

Tags: xcode, macports

I was had to reinstall Xcode 4 and now I'm getting message `Xcode appears to be installed but xcodebuild is unusable;` and `xcodebuild exists but failed to execute` all the time when I try to install **anything** using ports:

```
ash-3.2$ sudo port install wget
Password:
Warning: xcodebuild exists but failed to execute
Warning: configured user/group adm does not exist, will build as root
Warning: Xcode appears to be installed but xcodebuild is unusable; some ports will likely fail to build.
Warning: You may need to run `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app`
--->  Computing dependencies for wget
```

xcodebuild exists but it wants to another one xcodebuild or it just wants to be in `/Developer` folder?

```
$ which xcodebuild
/usr/bin/xcodebuild

$ /usr/bin/xcodebuild 
error: can't exec '/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild' (No such file or directory)
```

What's wrong with this utility? How can I fix it (I've already reinstalled Xcode)?

---

**Update:**
`port` worked fine even without `xcodebuild`, I think MacPorts uses `make` and it showed this message just to make me know that I may have a problems with Xcode.

That's interesting. I've tried `… xcode-select …` but for some reason it newer worked even after reboot, but today it worked :|. It asked me if I want to accept the license agreement and after I accepted it `xcodebuild` become functional. So now I can accept answer and thank everybody.

Comment: As far as I know, XCode 3 was installed in /Developer, but XCode 4 is installed as an Application in /Applications. (I haven't installed XCode 4 yet) Are you sure XCode 3 was properly uninstalled?

Comment: I've never had Xcode 3 on this computer. I've reinstalled Xcode 4 from App Store after removing older Xcode 4 which didn't wanted to start.

Comment: You might try what SSteve suggests. My guess is that there is a file somewhere that thinks that you have XCode 3 installed. :|

Comment: D'oh it was in my question. I've just copied it without looking :( I've ran xcode-select but it didn't hellped yet.

Comment: Just a tip that’s unrelated to your problem: you may want to use [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) instead of MacPorts.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Did you run `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app`? This message: `error: can't exec '/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild'` is telling you that your system is looking for xcodebuild in `/Developer/usr/bin/' but as of Xcode 4.3 (the one that's installed from the App Store) it's located in the Xcode.app bundle which is in /Applications.

**Edit**

In a comment to your question you say you've run `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app`. Now run `xcode-select -print-path` and make sure it says "/Applications/Xcode.app".

Also, you may need to [download the command line tools separately](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/1006-SW2). (I don't know from first-hand experience because I'm stuck on Snow Leopard for the moment so I haven't installed Xcode 4.3.)

Answer (score 9):

As stated here https://trac.macports.org/wiki/ProblemHotlist, you need to run:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: // , Thanks for the command and the link, @Gabriele Bartolini. I had a question, though, to which I hope you might know the answer. Why not just `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app`, or, in the case of Xcode Beta users, just `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app`? Why does this answer add the additional `/Contents/Developer`?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. After upgrading to Mountain Lion and upgrading Xcode to version 4.4.1 including the command-line tools, I could not call xcodebuild from the terminal anymore.

Then I stumbled upon a setting in Xcode's preferences where I had to choose which command-line tools I wanted to use, a bit silly since there were only one option.

[image]

http://thomas.bindzus.me/2012/08/17/after-upgrading-to-mountain-lions-problems/

I found this to be the easiest way to restore my command-line tools.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create simple "mac os x" project using "command line tools", after that you will be able to download command line tools from xcode->pref's->downloads in components.
it's size 115.6MB

Comment: Can you describe in a bit more details what you mean with the first sentence? How would one do that?

Comment: // , This is an interesting idea, @Serj. May we know more?

Answer (score 1):

I had very recently installed Xcode (along with the command line tools) on High Sierra (10.13.4) and I only fixed this error message by accepting the Xcode license via the command line:

`sudo xcodebuild -license`